# Allow navigation in Android webview

Tags: java, android, webview

I'm creating an application where I'm opening a website inside a webview.

So the website is all about booking a kind of service. And there's a few steps in the website.

First the user can choose what kind of service to book, and then the user clicks on the button "Continue". But the problem is, when the user clicks on the button the website just getting relaoded, which means, we're not getting navigated to the next step.

Is there anything I have to change in the code?

So I would like to navigate to the next "step" in the webview once the user clicks on a button. But instead the website is just getting relaoded and all the data is "lost".

```
    public void webView(){
    WebView webview = view.findViewById(R.id.service_webview);

    WebSettings settings = webview.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webview.loadUrl("https://www.HIDDENURL.com/book/choose-service");
}
```

I'm allowing Javascript. But is there anything else I have to add to accomplish this?

NOTE! I'm not owning the website, so I cannot change anything.
NOTE! When I click on "continue" the other page is "opening" for a milisecond, then automatically closes and starts over.

Comment: check whether the url is working fine in device browser

Comment: @Jacks If I run it in the real webbrowser it does work fine.

Comment: did you try it in device browser ? also do you have android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" in you manifest ?

Comment: @Jacks I tried it by going in the simulator -> webbrowser -> enter the URL -> testing

I do not have that in my Manifest. Can I add it straight up like you provided?

Comment: @Jacks So I added that, but the website is still not letting me navigate

Comment: yes please try adding that, some times app blocks some urls. also try web.loadUrl("https://www.google.com") instead of your url

Comment: @Jacks Well, the website is showing correctly. But once I try to navigate it does not let me. (When I click a button INSIDE the website of the webview)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204616/discussion-between-jacks-and-putte).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was with the Ajax call in your website which will load a particular section in the page, you will have to enable DomStorage also to achieve this.

```
 public void webView(){
        WebView webview = view.findViewById(R.id.service_webview);

        WebSettings settings = webview.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webview.loadUrl("https://www.HIDDENURL.com/book/choose-service");
    }
```

Comment: That works perfectly fine.

Thanks a lot for all your input in chat and here. Much appreciated!